# Is it possible to have both synchronous and asynchonous plugin running post creation of record?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

We have a business need where we need to create up to 50,000 records. Using a synchronous plugin or javascript is not acceptable solution here because it takes too long-- SQL timeout will occur. Is it possible? Can we run asynchronous & synchronous plugin on the same PostOperation Create step of that entity?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, yes. You cannot have same step as both sync and Async but You can register two steps, one as synchronous and another one as asynchronous. Make sure you are not doing the same logic in those steps in same plugin.

You can split the logic in two plugins and register the two separate steps carefully wrt what is need in sync mode vs Async mode.

Normally, If you want to Rollup the DB transaction when the logic fails - then synchronous step is needed. If the logic failure is not a show stopper and can silently fail to move forward - then asynchronous is enough (write a plugin trace log entry in `try..catch` for analysis).

Assembly (.dll) can have two plugins (.cs file), and multiple steps for each plugin is possible. But maintain the clarity for less complexity and maintenance.